# jsf loosing url param after session-timeout

Tags: session-timeout, jsf-2.2

jsf page uses `<f:viewParam>` and `<f:viewAction>` in order to take url parameters and open the page normally.

I also used

```
<f:event type="preRenderView"/>
```

In that behavior is normally

On session lose if refreshing page or pressing enter in the url the page redirects to the login page where username and password are entered and the returns to the initial page having the parameters.

But in case session is lost and user clicks any button (an action button not a linl to a page) in the page the page redirects to the login page with the initial url but with no parameters

Example URL: localhost:8080/newProject/views/page1?id=1

In first case the same url is redirected to , but in second case it redirects to localhost:8080/newProject/views/page1 loosing the parameter id=1

Java code:

```
private Item item;

@EJB
ItemFacade itemFacade;

private String id;

public String getId(){
   return id;
}

public void setId(String id){
   this.id=id;
}

public void init(){
   item= itemFacade.find(id);
}
```

JSF code:

```
<f:viewParam name="id" value="#{myBean.id}"/>
<f:viewAction value="#{myBean.init()}" onPostback="false"/>
```

Comment: I don't see any buttons in your page… and how do you redirect to the loginpage? Maybe you forget to add the parameters in the 'original url' page where after login you should be send to

Comment: according to security configurations in web.xml after session timeout the page will redirect to the login page by changing the url of the page you were in by removing ?id=1 while in other url not having parameter (?id=1) rediredction is to login page then to the page you were in